# On the density of this set in L^2[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is part of an example in Rudin's Functional Analysis, in the chapter on unbounded operators. It needs to be shown that the set of absolutely continuous functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ with square integrable derivatives satisfying $f(0)=f(1)=0$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$.

All polynomials are absolutely continuous and their derivatives lie in $L^2[0,1]$. Weierstrass theorem implies then that the set of absolutely continuous functions with square integrable derivatives is dense in $L^2[0,1]$. But what about the condition that $f(0)=f(1)$.

I am not sure that this is the right approach to take. I would be grateful for some hints.

Comment: By multiplying a continuous cutoff function $g_n$ such that $g_n=1$ for all $\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq 1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $g(0) = g(1)=0$, then $g_nf \to f$ in $L^2$.